# How to add days in current days dynamically in php

Tags: php

Currently i am working on creating ecommerce website in that on order return section user can only return goods for particular time from the time product was delivered.(Ex. if product is deliver on `10-7-2018` and return day vale in database is `10` than after `20-7-2018` the button of return should hide automatically.

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d"); //Current Date
$date3 = $return_days['value']; //Day count value
//echo $date3.'<br>'; //it will print day count value                                           
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($num['updated_date'] .'+'.$date3)); // i am adding $date3 and $num['updated_date'] value
```

if `$num['updated_date']` value is `10-7-2018` and `$date3` value is `10` than output of `$date2` should `20-7-2018` but my code is not giving desired output.

If any body know solution than please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object and add days using `modify()` method like below:

```
$daysForReturn = 10;

$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify("+$daysForReturn day");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Output: 2018-08-24
```

Comment: the Value of 10 is not always the same, it should be dynamic as per his explanation above

Comment: It's not a big deal just put a value of variable instead of hardcoding it

Comment: Was about to write a similar solution, +1 yours instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, try this code below:

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d"); //Current Date
$daysCount = $return_days['value']; //Day count value
$returnDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($num['updated_date'] .'+'.$daysCount.' days'));
echo $returnDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code works :

```
$Date = "2018-08-14"; // your delivery date
$days = "10"; /// extended days
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + '.$days.' days')); /// result
```